# Sticky position on y axis

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use 2 sticky positions in `display: flex` format

[here is the html format preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t2rq.png)

on this image red is sticky on x, working correctly there is no problem but the green side is not working, it must be sticky on the y axis.

[here is the html flex structre and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35bYv.png)

I think there is no problem with the flex structure, but I don't know why the red side works but the green side does not.

and here is the snippet

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 26px;
}


div.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.column.top {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
}

.product {
    background-color: chartreuse!important;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column top">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="row product">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not post images of your code: use the code snippet feature in the rich text editor to add a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

I removed your `overflow-x: scroll;` and `overflow-y: hidden;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 26px;
}


div.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.column.top {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
}

.product {
    background-color: chartreuse!important;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    inset-inline:0;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column top">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="row product">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thats it thank you so much, but i have 1 more question why overflow options trigger it? <3

Comment: because sticky is relative to body, when you give the container itself overflow, the sticky element never stick to edge cause you are scrolling another element not the body.